# iOS Alternate Icon not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I have followed few tutorials on setting alternative icons in iOS but I cannot get it to work properly. The important part in my Info.plist looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>default</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>six</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>six</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>crazy</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>crazy</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

And the code for the view controller, very simple:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@objc func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    var icon: String?
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 1:
        icon = "six"
    case 2:
        icon = "crazy"
    default:
        icon = nil
    }
    changeIcon(icon)
}

func changeIcon(_ icon: String?) {
    if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons {
        UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(icon, completionHandler: { (error) in
            print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        })
    }
  }
}
```

When the method gets called I get prompt saying

> You have changed the icon for "App".

But the icon that is displayed is the default one
My icon files are named: six@2x.png, six@3x.png, crazy@2x.png, crazy@3x.png, default@2x.png, default@3x.png
Why is it not changing? Are there any special steps for putting the image files in the project? I have put mine in the "res" folder

Project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nboslz2s6gagvwl/AltIcon.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please more clarify your question what you want exactly.

Comment: There is a property called `alternativeIconName` on `UIApplication`, for debugging it would be useful to print the name before you try to change it. To see if any path information is included.

Comment: It prints correct name of the icon, but it doesn't change.

Comment: What if you move them to the general project directory instead of the 'res' folder?

Comment: Nothing changes, I have uploaded the project to dropbox

Comment: I download your project I noticed a bunch of errors.  You images are not png files. If you re-save them as png it works just.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, seems like the software I use to scale images doesn't save PNG files properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was problem with the software I was using to scale down images, it wasn't saving PNG files properly.

Comment: What is 'not properly'? What did you change to fix it?

Comment: I saved them again using `Preview` app on Mac, it worked fine after it

Comment: This helped! I was having the same exact issue as the OP. My icon files were saved as JPG. Once I saved them to PNG the icons changed properly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the image Png not accept jpg or jpeg

Answer (score -1):

After researching for several minutes, finally, I found my fault. If your implementation looking like perfect and there is no reason to not working, here is the point:

In my case, I triggered `UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("ICON_NAME")` in `viewDidLoad()` method in the view controller I created, right after triggered splash screen, called `AfterSplashViewController`.

This view controller is like a router, looks as same as possible launch screen also has several businesses logic like a route to the app or login screen, etc.

Long story short, after called `setAlternateIconName()` method, the system shows a popup to the user to notify the app icon change with default text. In your situation, if your logic has no time to show this popup via a reason, this method will not work and your app icons will not change.

Just for sure to trigger 'setAlternateIconName()` method in your codebase, just in the right place.

Happy coding.